# pipenv - No module named tensorflow despite it is installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm, pipenv

I am not able to import `tensorflow` (gives error when I do) despite it is already installed. Here is the content of my `Pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
tensorflow = "*"
numpy = "*"
scipy = "*"
scikit-learn = "*"
pillow = "*"
h5py = "*"
keras = "*"
opencv-python = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

**Things I have already tried to fix this issue:**

- Executed `pipenv update`
- Executed `pipenv install tensorflow`
- Click to `install package tensorflow` prompt in `PyCharm`

Python version: `Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

**The output of `pip debug --verbose`:**

```
pip version: pip 19.2.3 from d:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-pqstp19f\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
sys.version: 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
sys.executable: d:\.virtualenvs\keras-fer-pqstp19f\scripts\python.exe
sys.getdefaultencoding: utf-8
sys.getfilesystemencoding: utf-8
locale.getpreferredencoding: cp1252
sys.platform: win32
sys.implementation:
  name: cpython
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Compatible tags: 14
  cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
  cp37-none-win_amd64
  py3-none-win_amd64
  cp37-none-any
  cp3-none-any
  py37-none-any
  py3-none-any
  py36-none-any
  py35-none-any
  py34-none-any
  py33-none-any
  py32-none-any
  py31-none-any
  py30-none-any
```

Comment: Are you running in a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, I am running these commands in the venv.

Comment: Can you also post the output of `pip debug --verbose` (or the equivalent for pipenv)? Are you on a 32 bits system/python?

Comment: No, I am using the 64-bit version on Windows 10. @MihaiMaruseac

Comment: Full version info is added to OP.

Comment: From your output: `..on win32`. Please post the output of `pip debug --verbose` to be sure, but I think you might be hitting https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32315

Comment: was your virtual environment activated when you installed Tensorflow? If you're unsure I'd activate environment and try to install again.

Comment: Added @MihaiMaruseac. Yes, I think so as I have created it via PyCharm as I always do. Have not experienced any issues except than this.

Comment: `platform.architecture()[0]` validates it is 64-bit. @MihaiMaruseac

Comment: Python version and pip version seem to be incompatible.